# Ввод нескольких строк в командную строку и запись в двумерный массив

Tags: java, массивы

Необходимо вставить (Ctrl + v) в командную строку двумерный массив размерностью KxL в виде:

kfn3p
j5ngi
idoen
ofign
msigf

и внести каждый символ в двумерный массив (array[0][0] = 'k' ; array[0][1] = 'f' ; array[1][0] = 'j';  и т.д.)

Answer (score 0):

```
static char[][] заводимМассив(int K, int L) {
    
    // Создаем новый массив заданного размера
    char[][] массив = new char[K][L];
    
    // Открываем читалку консоли, можно и Scanner, если удобнее.
    try (BufferedReader читаемСтроки = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        // Перебираем строки
        for (int ё = 0; ё < K; ё++) {

/*Тут считываем очередную строку разбиваем ее на массив, методом .toCharArray()
и сразу присваиваем массиву.
если массив нужен String[][] то разбивку делаем методом .split("") */
            массив[ё] = читаемСтроки.readLine().toCharArray();
            }
            
// возвращаем готовый массив, запросу char[][] массив = заводимМассив(K, L);
            return массив;

//Если что-то не так то кинем исключение, или можно закомментировать и вернуть null;
    } catch (IOException чтотоНеТак) {
        чтотоНеТак.printStackTrace();
        return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Обрати внимание, при Ctrl + v нужно копировать с дополнительным переводом каретки(enter), чтобы читалка понимала что последняя строка закончена.

Comment: Не пишите комментарии, [правте ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1282844/edit).